# Order of evaluation in ABAP

Tags: abap

Does ABAP have a defined order of evaluation?  For example, in an expression `foo( ) + bar( )`, is there a guarantee which of the methods `foo( )` and `bar( )` is evaluated/executed first?  Couldn't find such info in the ABAP Keyword Documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ABAP documentation: arith_exp - Arithmetic Operators](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenarith_operators.htm):

> The table shows the possible arithmetic operators for arithmetic expressions, their priority, and the order in which the calculation is performed.
>
> Within a parenthesis level, calculations with operators of higher priority are performed before calculations with operators of lower priority.
>
> For adjacent operators of the same priority, the calculation is performed in the order specified.
>
> In the third column of the table below, 3 indicates the highest priority and 1 the lowest. 
>
> `Operator  Priority  Order`              
> `+         1         From left to right` 
> `-         1         From left to right` 
> `*         2         From left to right` 
> `/         2         From left to right` 
> `DIV       2         From left to right` 
> `MOD       2         From left to right` 
> `**        3         From right to left`

Comment: Similar to this, something I quickly searched for but did not find either:
If we have a condition like `IF foo( ) OR bar( ).`
If `foo( )` returns abap_true, will `bar( )` be called at all?

Because if not, that could make for some nice and easy performance optimizations

Comment: @KevinHoltkamp Answer is in ABAP doc [log_exp - Boolean Operators and Parentheses](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenlogexp_boole.htm). Better create a dedicated question and answer yourself.